# Recursion inside for loop confuses me

Tags: javascript, for-loop, recursion

I am trying to get this pattern:

```
[
  [,,2],
  [,2,1],
  [2,1,0]
]
```

and I tried the following code:

```js
let n = 3
let mainArr = Array(n)
for (let i = 0; i < mainArr.length; i++) {
  mainArr[i] = new Array(n)
}
let odi = 0; // stands for one dimensional index
let tdi = n - 1; // stands for two dimensional index
let diagonalValue = n - 1;
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  recur(odi, tdi)
  odi++;
  tdi--;
  diagonalValue--;
}

function recur(frst, scnd) {
  if (mainArr[frst] === undefined || mainArr[scnd] === undefined) {
    return
  } else {
    mainArr[frst][scnd] = diagonalValue;
    return recur(frst + 1, scnd - 1)
  }
}

console.log(mainArr);
```

but I got this output :

```
[
  [,,2],
  [,1,],
  [0,,]
]
```

So I think I'm missing something about the recursion when its used inside for loops, because I solved many problems using recursion but only with casual way without using it inside a for loop.

Can you please explain to me what happens when we use a recursive function inside a `for` loop. Does it call itself along with each iteration or the for loop waits until the recursive function finishes and then the loop moves to the next iteration?

Comment: As to your final question: this you can analyse yourself with a debugger. Step through the code and inspect variables.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function which keeps the last inserted array.

```js
function fill(n, array = Array(n + 1)) {
    array = array.slice(1);
    array.push(n);
    return [array, ...(n ? fill(n - 1, array) : [])]
}

console.log(fill(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your attempt:

In `recur` you use `scnd` as index of the outer dimension. That is the wrong dimension for that index. You should change the `if` condition from:

```
 if (mainArr[frst] === undefined || mainArr[scnd] === undefined) {
```

to this:

```
 if (mainArr[frst] === undefined || scnd < 0) {
```

In the main program you presumably want to call `recur` to fill a diagonal of the matrix, but then the `tdi` value should not change between iterations: each diagonal starts in the same column.

So here is your code with the minimum corrections needed:

```js
let n = 3
let mainArr = Array(n)
for (let i = 0; i < mainArr.length; i++) {
  mainArr[i] = new Array(n)
}
let odi = 0; // stands for one dimensional index
let tdi = n - 1; // stands for two dimensional index
let diagonalValue = n - 1;
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  recur(odi, tdi)
  odi++;
  diagonalValue--;
}

function recur(frst, scnd) {
  if (mainArr[frst] === undefined || scnd < 0) {
    return
  } else {
    mainArr[frst][scnd] = diagonalValue;
    return recur(frst + 1, scnd - 1)
  }
}

console.log(mainArr);
```

Of course, there are other ways to produce this result, often shorter. The recursion here can be easily converted to just iteration, so I would not go for the recursive solution here.

For instance:

```js
let n = 3;
let mainArr = [];
for (let row = 0; row < n; row++) {
    mainArr[row] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= row; i++) {
        mainArr[row][n - 1 - row + i] = n - 1 - i;
    }
}

console.log(mainArr);
```